# What are the steps to re-enable replication if replica-server lost the replicated vms?

Tags: replication, windows-server-2019

We just lost our logical drive for a few replicated VMs and couldn't restore them. Now we ran into the issue that we can't re-enable the replication process on the primary Hyper-V Host.

We get the following error:

`[Window Title]
Enable Replication
[Main Instruction]
Enabling replication failed.
[Content]
Hyper-V failed to enable replication.
[Expanded Information]
Hyper-V failed to enable replication for virtual machine 'printserver02': Unspecified error (0x80004005). (Virtual machine ID 40D90686-7ECC-4162-83A9-BF3457D24AF9)`

We tried to remove any information of the lost vms in Hyper-V configuration (ProgrammData, AppData), restartet the machine, but no luck.

Is there a way to achieve this the correct way without resetting VMId by duplicating the vms?

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V reinstall solved this issue for us.

1. Remove Hyper-V
2. Delete Hyper-V files from C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V
3. Reinstall Hyper-V

We use Certificate based authentication, so we had to create new certificate on replica server.

After these steps we was able to re-enable replication.